# How to convert a Void function with a closure as parameter to a closure?

Tags: swift

This is my function in below:

```
func myFunction(value: (String) -> Void) {
    value("Hello")
}
```

with use case of:

```
myFunction(value: { newValue in
     print(newValue)
})
```

I want convert this function to a closure:

I made this one:

```
typealias Action = () -> Void

let myClosure: (Action) -> Void = { action in
    action()
}
```

and the use case is:

```
myClosure {
    print("Hello")
}
```

But as you can see `myClosure` cannot set the string, I want be able to do this code:

```
myClosure { newValue in
    print(newValue)
}
```

need help to solve this slippery codes.

Comment: The answer is literally in the first code line in your question, `(String) -> Void)` or am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing that anyone can have a question about the thing that they did not know about it, and that is what you are missing. For some one like me something like `(String) -> Void)` and for you the philosophy of the question. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Yes but it’s not wrong to ask since sometimes you as the reader or OP might actually have missed something in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add a generic type parameter to your `Action` typealias:

```
typealias Action<T> = (T) -> Void
```

and define `myClosure` like this:

```swift
let myClosure: Action<String> = { newValue in
    print(newValue)
}
myClosure("hello")
myClosure("world")
```

##### Output

> hello
> world

Comment: Good answer; this is a complete-as-possible translation of [C#'s `Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 1):

You only need one small change to your "closure" attempt to replicate your "function" approach.

You need to add a `String` parameter to your `typealias` and then pass a string when calling `action`:

```
typealias Action = (String) -> Void // Add the String parameter

let myClosure: (Action) -> Void = { action in
    action("Hello") // Call action with a string
}
```

Now when you do:

```
myClosure { newValue in
    print(newValue)
}
```

you will get the output:

> Hello

Answer (score 1):

**Intuition**

- Just as `myFunction` takes a closure that takes a `string` as input and returns `void`, the `myClosure` should do the same.
- Later by passing the `print` function as an argument to `myClosure`, we can print the string `Hello`.

**Code**

```swift
typealias Action = (String) -> Void

let myClosure: (Action) -> Void = { action in
    action("Hello")
}

myClosure { arg in
    print(arg)
}
```